# Error downloading file from a given URL

Tags: url, java

I am trying to download the given URL:
 `http://www.addic7ed.com/original/9521/7`

but when i try to download the file using my Java Code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.addic7ed.com/original/9521/7");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("abc.srt"); 
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

The `html page` gets downloaded whereas the file to be downloaded should be a `.srt extension` file.

But when I try to download the above link using `Internet Download Manager` the file gets downloaded.

`IDM` converts the above given URL into `http://www.addic7ed.com/srtcache/Supernatural/Supernatural%20-%2004x06%20-%20Yellow%20Fever.720p%20CTU.English.orig.Addic7ed.com.srt`

So my question is how to achieve this in JAVA...?? Are there any API available to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried using `http://www.addic7ed.com/original/9521/7` (with `http://` added to the front)?

Comment: yes i tried but the html page is getting downloaded..

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the HTML file?  I suspect that it is actually an error page from the server, and that it contains clues about what is actually going on.

Here are some possibilities:

- Maybe you need to supply authentication credentials.
- Maybe the server is sending a redirect (3xx) response, and that the client side is not performing the redirect.
- Maybe you need to set some extra headers to make the server realize that it should not turn the response as HTML.  For example, an Accept header.

But note that the details will depend on the server that you are trying to talk to.

---

If I was trying to download files programmatically in Java, I would either use `HttpUrlConnection` or the Apache `HttpClient` libraries.  Both will give you more control over the download process than simply using `URL.openStream()`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the http response from http://www.addic7ed.com/original/9521/7 is a 302 redirect which your java code is not correctly handling.  IDM correctly handles the redirect. A great tool to use if you are on a *nix based systme, or have cygwin installed on windows is curl.

curl -v http://myurl

will display all the http traffic information (request/response)

Comment: Furthermore: you may want to look into Apache Commons HTTPClient.  I believe that supports redirects out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with?

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.addic7ed.com/original/9521/7");
```

Comment: I've just checked the link, it is a webpage, that's why you get a webpage :)

Comment: but how come internet download manager is able to fetch the link i really want to download. It is not downloading the webpage. It is downloading the .SRT file

Comment: internet download manager is familiar with addic7ed.com and knows how to download the files it hosts, bypassing the HTML page.

Comment: so is there anything i can do to download the link...using java or any other language.

Comment: Also notice you get a 302 HTTP code and then it gets redirected to http://addic7ed.com/serie/Supernatural/4/6/addic7ed when you GET the provided URL

Comment: Yes, download the file from: http://www.addic7ed.com/srtcache/Supernatural/Supernatural%20-%2004x06%20-%20Yellow%20Fever.720p%20CTU.English.orig.Addic7ed.com.srt

Comment: No, I mean this: URL url = new URL("http://www.addic7ed.com/srtcache/Supernatural/Supernatural%20-%2004x06%20-%20Yellow%20Fever.720p%20CTU.English.orig.Addic7ed.com.srt");

Comment: actually i am trying make a java program where user had to enter the (TV Series name,season number and episode number) and the subtitles will get downloaded automatically. Therefore when i scrapped the given html page i got this [http://www.addic7ed.com/original/9521/7] as my link. So am trying to download this link.

Comment: Then you should follow step by step what that url does: It first returns an HTTP result of 302 with a location "/srtcache/blahblah.srt". Then it gets redirected to that location hitting the file. See that? Now, as of my few tries, you WON'T be able to fech the file if you do not set the proper REFERER header to the HTTP request (fake it as if you were a browser), and that should be enough. I've used Referer=http://www.addic7ed.com/serie/Supernatural/4/6/addic7ed

Comment: srry i didn't get u at all....how did u know first it returns a HTTP(302) request with "/srtcache/ghgh.srt" location.

Comment: Oh. Download Firefox, download Tamper Data plugin, disable javascript and play around... you'll see what I a talking about. Then remove the Referer item and you'll see what I mean ;) That's all no more commenting it is getting loooong